# Is my pork roast bad?

Tags: food-safety

I put my pork loin roast in the Crock-Pot with the juices and seasoning last night at about 10 it was on for about an hour. I think it accidentally got unplugged around 11 and sat till 6 in the morning . I turned it back on. Is it safe to eat?

Comment: No, the food almost certainly would have been in the danger zone over the allowable time.

Comment: Thought maybe this was a quality-related question, and came here to sign up for the free samples you were going to mail out.  :(